# Redirect in httpd-vhosts.conf not working as expected with XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts

Using Windows 10 and XAMPP, I have a redirect for a virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/yoursite.com
    ServerName yoursite.com
    <Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/yoursite.com>
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        Allow From All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule (.*) capture.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

capture.php, at this point, just says hello and echoes the URL. This works perfectly until I create an .htaccess file: yoursite.com/.htaccess. If the .htaccess file is empty, or contains just comments, the redirect still works as expected. If the .htaccess file contains anything else, even a rule that has no effect, I get a 404. Here's an example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^nosuchhost
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/mysite.com/index.php
```

This condition will never be met and the rule will never apply, but it still prevents the redirect from the httpd-vhosts.conf file and throws a 404.

The .htaccess file is clearly being read, as is the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

If Apache finds rewrite rules in a local .htaccess file, does it throw out and forget all rewrite rules it got from the httpd-vhosts.conf file? Or have I got something wrong?

Here is the content of the windows hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       yoursite.com
```

Comment: Why don't I just put the redirect in .htaccess?  It's complicated. I'm trying to create a kind of unit test for sets of .htaccess rewrite rules. The .htaccess file will be written dynamically based on a set of inputs so it needs to be independent of the redirect.

Comment: Actually you should always prefer _not_ to use dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"), but to implement such rules in the http servers static configuration files. Dynamic files make things complex, are hard to debug due to surprising side effects, they really slow the server down and they open huge security issues, _especially_ if the http server process is able to write them.

Comment: I don't really see what the specific issue is with your setup above, but give it a try and move the rewriting rules out of the `<Directory>` section into the global host configuration. You will need to drop the `RewriteBase` for that and use an absolute path as rewriting target.

Comment: Agreed (on the dynamic configuration) but not everyone has access to the Apache config files. I understand the security issues, but doesn't and may never run on a production server.  And, I already have a surprising side effect. ;)

The question remains: does Apache forget about the rewrite rules in config when it finds an .htaccess file that has some?  I could find nothing on this in the Apache docs.

Comment: The clear answer is: no, the apache http server does not "forget" any rules. But what I don't understand: In your quesiton you clearly state that you _do_ have access to the server configuration.

Comment: As I said, it's complicated. The rule in the config file is necessary to help  capture the final URL generated by the .htaccess file. The .htaccess file needs to contain only the rules for producing that URL. So, If the server does not "forget" the rules, why are the rules in the config file applied when there is no .htaccess file, but not applied when the .htaccess file contains nothing but unrelated rules or even rules that the won't ever be applied. (Also  - Moving them from the vhosts file to the main config file doesn't change anything.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I always referred to what you call "vhosts file", that _is_ the http servers host configuration as opposed to dynamic configuration files (.htaccess). Whether your http server configuration is split into several files or written monolitic is irrelevant.

Comment: I really thought I'd found the answer with adding RewriteOptions Inherit in the vhosts file, but it didn't change anything. The rewrite rule in vhosts still results in a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to sound kind of unbelievable, but after trying every possible solution, I finally tried deleting a bunch of comments in .htaccess that contained rewrite conditions and rules. After doing that, everything began working as it should.

It doesn't make sense, because the first thing any decent parser will do is strip out all the comments, but I have no other explanation. (And yes, I made sure that there were no stray uncommented rules in the set.)

Now that things are working, I can verify that the comments by arkascha are correct, it doesn't matter where the conditions and rules are, they are all applied.